# search for all strings start with and end with c# regex

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to find all strings that start with `"<!--Buy_"` and ends with `"_thumbnail-->"`
 in c# regex

```
Regex Regex = new Regex("^<!--Buy_(.*)_thumbnail-->$");
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches("<!--Buy_blabla_thumbnail-->").Count);
```

the code print zero ...
what is the problem with my regex pattren and how to fix it ?

Comment: also do not name your local variable the same as the Object name change the casing something like `Regex regEx = new RegEx`

Comment: Are you also trying to match the "\ at the beginning of the string? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: I get 1 with the exact same code (after adding the missing quotation marks in the second line)

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use [`string.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`string.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a regular expression?

Comment: yes i am trying to print the inner string between the start and the end not to check if the string is match ...

Comment: Updated my answer so you return whats inbetween the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first you should never call your `regex regex`, that itself might break your application

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(<!--Buy_)(.*?)(_thumbnail-->)");
```

Based on the new information that you are looking for the specific string located between the start and the end, then I would use this regex -

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(?<=<!--Buy_)(.*?)(?=_thumbnail-->)");
```

This will give you everything between "buy_" and "_thumbnail"

Comment: your code won't compile it should be 
`Regex reg = new Regex`

Comment: Also you're missing `);` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to use a regular expressions when you can just use `string.StartsWith` and `string.EndsWith`

```
bool isMatch = yourString.StartsWith("<!--Buy_") 
            && yourString.EndsWith("_thumbnail-->");

string between = isMatch ? yourString.Substring(8, yourString.Length - 21) : null;
```

Comment: i am trying to print the inner string between the start and the end not to check if the string is match ..

Comment: @idokahana Once you know it's a match it's just a simple `yourString.Substring(8, yourString.Length - 21);`

Comment: yes but the string can hold more information i just trying to found the spicefic tag .

Comment: @idokahana Wait, so it's not that the string begins and ends with those values, but it has a specific tag somewhere within it?  It's starting to sound like you actually need a xml parser.